# ESC not starting the motor

Tags: microcontroller, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, keil

I have a 20A ESC, I have connected it to the brushless dc motor as shown in picture. When i apply a 1ms + signal with rate of 50hz it produces beeps but doesn do any thing. i have connected the wire to mc as; the red one to +5 black to gnd, and white to MC for apply pulse. where am i doing it wrong.[image]

[image]

Comment: I have the same one , you have to calibrate it first also it has a safety feature that don't let you start the motor unless you start with the lowest frequency

Comment: how have you started it to work. please give me your

Comment: the delay function in c language

Comment: sorry not in  C just a test run with arduino

Comment: ok you can give me a delay function in ms

Comment: using the servo library `servo.WriteMicroseconds()` the lowest supported delay for this ESC was 1300 microSecond and the highest is 1800 microSecond, did you receive the instruction paper with it ?

Answer (score 2):

The ESC is likely treating the length of a control pulse at power-on as zero throttle (for safety). Change the pulse to 1500 us after ESC stops beeping and it should start your motor.

Comment: ok let me check this

Comment: sir, i think i have problems in my delay function,
void delay(unsigned int itime)
{
unsigned int i,j;
for (i=0;i<itime;i++) // this is For(); loop delay used to define delay value in Embedded C
{
for (j=0;j<1200;j++);
}
}

Comment: please give me a proper millisecond delay function

Comment: this is not relevant to the question

Comment: ok i have done what you have said, but nothing changed.

Comment: i gavve 1500us pulse at 50hz delay. i.e 20ms delay b/w 1500us positive pulses. it does nothing.
when i plug on the motor and esc, it beeps as 123, and then no sound, now i plug on the mccontroller, and keeps the pwm at 1000us to keep it off, after 10 sec i change the pwm to 1500us, but nothing happens, no sound, no buzzing.

Comment: This is probably not sufficient.  Typically, today's ESC's require something like minimum throttle, maximum, then back to minimum before they will arm.  Note that many can be reflashed with alternate firmwares which may give you additional command options such as i2c.

Answer (score 2):

Most (if not all) ESCs expect a short pulse at power up. Set it initially to 900us and wait until the beeps stop (~3 seconds).
A long pulse (~1500us) at power up will get the ESC into the programming mode.